# IndexingError / "Too many indexers" with DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the following (partial) df:

```
Month  SUBTYPE  DEPSTN  ARRSTN  Flight Nr  Airline
1      332      AMS     IAD     651        KLM        1
                IAD     AMS     652        KLM        1
       333      AMS     IAD     651        KLM        1
                IAD     AMS     652        KLM        1
       73H      ABZ     AMS     1444       KLM        1
                AMS     ABZ     1443       KLM        1
                        BGO     1189       KLM        1
                        EDI     1279       KLM        1
                        MAN     1081       KLM        1
                BGO     AMS     1190       KLM        1
                CDG     AMS     1224       KLM        1
                EDI     AMS     1280       KLM        1
                MAN     AMS     1082       KLM        1
       73W      ABZ     AMS     1440       KLM        1
...
Name: Legs, Length: 782, dtype: int64
```

If I call `df.loc[1, '332', 'ALA', 'AMS', 410, 'KLM']` it returns an IndexingError indicating 'Too many indexers'. However, if I call `df.loc[1, '73W', 'ABZ', 'AMS', 1440, 'KLM']` it returns the proper value (`1`).

Besides the fact that I cannot seem to explain this behaviour, the core of the problem is that using a Try/Except-block, I can't Except on the IndexingError and set a default value in case a particular flight cannot be found in the df.

Due to workplace software limitations, I'm using Pandas 0.14 on Python 3.4.1.

Thanks for all help and tips!

Comment: I've currently solved this by matching the indices between this dataframe and the dataframe where I had to include this data, and then simply call ``df1['col1'] = df2['col1']``.